# Why are we interested in this kind of second variation?

Tags: soft-question, riemannian-geometry, calculus-of-variations, harmonic-functions

**Short version:** why are we interested in two parameter-variations in 
contrast to one-parameter variations?

**Long version:**

In the literature on the calculus of variations, (specifically on harmonic mappings between Riemannian manifolds) one usually finds the following notion of **second variation**:

Let $M,N$ be Riemannian manifolds, $\phi:M \to N$ harmonic. Denote by $E$ the Dirichlet's energy functional, i.e $$ E(\phi)= \int_M |d\phi|^2\operatorname{dVol}_{M}$$
 We look at a smooth variation $\phi_{s,t}:M \to N$ with two parameters $s,t$, $\phi_{0,0}=\phi$, i.e a map $(-\epsilon,\epsilon) \times (-\epsilon,\epsilon) \times M \to N$.

Define $V=\left. \frac{d}{dt}\right|_{t=0} \phi_{0,t},W=\left. \frac{d}{ds}\right|_{s=0} \phi_{s,0}$, and

$$ H_{\phi}(V,W):=\left. \frac{\partial^2}{\partial s \partial t} \right|_{t=s=0} E(\phi_{s,t})$$

**My question:** What is the motivation for defining the variation in such a way?

All the applications I have seen were concerned only with analyzing $ \left. \frac{\partial^2}{\partial t^2} \right|_{t=0} E(\psi_{t})$ where $\psi_t$ is a one-parameter variation of $\phi$, satisfying $V=\left. \frac{d}{dt}\right|_{t=0} \psi_t$. (This is reasonable since the main issue is to determine the nature of $\phi$ as a critical point of $E$, i.e is it a local maximum,minmum or a saddle point).

Thus, I see no apparent reason for introducing the two-parameters when we can use only one parameter. This seems like an unneseccary complication.

Indeed the main definitions (like *weakly stable* etc) concern only
 $H_{\phi}(V,V)$ which is another way of saying** $ \left. \frac{\partial^2}{\partial t^2} \right|_{t=0} E(\psi_{t})$. Why do we bother to pass through the more general $H_{\phi}(V,W)$? Are there any advantages to that approach?

__

**Indeed, given $V$ and $\psi_t$ such that $V=\left. \frac{d}{dt}\right|_{t=0} \psi_t$, define $\phi_{s,t}=\psi_{s+t}$. Then $V=\left. \frac{d}{dt}\right|_{t=0} \phi_{0,t}=\left. \frac{d}{ds}\right|_{s=0} \phi_{s,0}$, and $H_{\phi}(V,V)=\left. \frac{\partial^2}{\partial s \partial t} \right|_{t=s=0} E(\phi_{s,t})=\left. \frac{\partial^2}{\partial s \partial t} \right|_{t=s=0} E(\psi_{s+t})=\left. \frac{\partial^2}{\partial t^2} \right|_{t=0} E(\psi_{t})$

Comment: As far as I know to invest fundamental group PIC manifolds we use this approach

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some thought, I came up witht the following:

$(1)$ The values of $H(V,V)$ for all $V$ uniquely determines $H(V,W)$ for all $V,W$, since $H$ is **symmetric** ($H(V,W)=H(W,V)$). Explicitly

$$ H(V,W)=\frac{1}{2}\big(H(V+W,V+W)-H(V,V)-H(W,W)\big), $$

so at least conceptually, it should not be harder to compute $H(V,W)$ than $H(V,V)$.

$(2)$ Point $(1)$ seems contradictory with what we know about analysis of critical points of functions $\mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$. In order to determine the nature of a critical point of $f$, one has to know all the entries of the Hessian, not just the diagonal. So how knowing only the "diagonal" values $H(V,V)$ suffices in our case?

The reason is that here we know $H(V,V)$ for **any V**. In the analogous situation for functions $f:\mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$, this corresponds to knowing $\operatorname{Hess} f(v,v)=v^T \cdot \operatorname{Hess} f \cdot v$ for **every** $v \in \mathbb{R}^n$, hence it enables us to determine whether or not the hessian is positive-definite for instance.

Indeed, knowing only the **diagonal elements of the hessian** does not suffice to determine the nature of critical points, since this  information is only about $\operatorname{Hess} f(e_i,e_i)$ (where $e_i$ are the standard basis vectors of $\mathbb{R}^n$).

Thus, there are really two different meanings here of what is the "diagonal"....

Answer (score 1):

One reason why this can be desirable is to check if a critical point of the functional is a minimum, a maximum, or just a flex point. This can be interesting for example if you are considering curves in a Riemannian manifold and your functional $E[\phi]$ is the length of the curve. Then minima correspond to geodesics.

Comment: 1) This does not explain why we need to compute $H(V,W)$. As I explained in my question, only the knowledge of $H(V,V)$ is required for determining the nature of the critical point. 2) Geodesics are critical points of the length functional, they are not always length minimizers (though locally they do minimize lenght, and yes, every minimizer is a geodesic).

Comment: @AsafShachar Are you sure you only need $\partial_t^2$? Think of $E$ as a function, then if you want to determine the kind of critical point you need the whole matrix of second derivatives - not just the diagonal - to determine whether $D^2E$ is positive definite, ...
Also, yeah maybe Riemannian geometry was not the best example, but if you had only a pseudo-metric then you might be interested in distinguishing the types of critical points.

Comment: Yes, I am sure about this. You can see my computation at the end of the question. Actually, our discussion made me realize we were confusing two differrent meanings of "knowledge of the diagonal". See my (new) answer below.